# Valid but spam data insertion into mySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, cordova

Background:
I'm creating an ios+android apps with PhoneGap and Jquery Mobile. My objective is to allow users to like certain features. I would like to limit one like per feature per app holder. Currently I'm doing this by creating an in-house unique id for each app (on install). This unique id is then sent via AJAX/JSON to REST API and INSERTed into a mySQL database on an external server. Each id then allows me to track likes per app and aggregate likes for features.

Question:
What is stopping someone from downloading my app, reading the source javascript/html, editing the source code to create new unique ids and flooding my db by inserting valid but garbage records? I.e. this attack would use a valid INSERT statement and hence security measures like stored procedure requests inside the db, hash and salt protecting passwords, HTTPS/SSL connection, blocks against SQL injection wouldn't stop it...

I am new to programmering web apps, so it's likely I've missed something fundamental but I would appreciate your help in helping me understand